# Casting an (NSString *) to (int *)?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, casting, struct, nsstring

I have an NSString.

```
NSString *str;
```

And I need to store it in a struct.

```
struct {
  int *s;
} st;
```

And set it.

```
st.s = str;
```

So, how should I go about retrieving it?

```
return (__bridge_retained NSString *)st.s;
```

I've tried the above, and it gives the error: Incompatible types casting 'int *' to 'NSString *' with a __bridge_retained cast.

---

Answered the question. Simply define the NSString in the struct like this.

```
struct {
  __unsafe_unretained NSString *s;
} st;
```

Thanks, Carl Veazey!

Comment: What's the significance of storing it as an `int *`? To get around ARC or is it actually a string representing an integer?

Comment: Thought storing them in struct as unsafe_unretained (holding strong reference elsewhere) was canonical way to do this? (or are you wanting a way to get around that too? just trying to clear up my understanding of the question)

Comment: So like this?

`struct {
    __unsafe_unretained int *s;
} st;`

Would you mind giving an example?

Comment: Oh! `__unsafe_unretained NSString *str;` inside the struct. Got it, thanks.

Comment: Yep! Just added an answer with references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To store an Objective-C object in an `struct` you have a couple of options, the one I see most is to store it in the struct as `__unsafe_unretained` and then maintain a `strong` reference to it elsewhere.

From the ["Common Issues While Converting a Project" section of the ARC Transition Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW16):

> If using Objective-C objects is sub-optimal, (maybe you want a dense
>   array of these structs) then consider using a void* instead. This
>   requires the use of the explicit casts...

They seem to imply `__bridge` is the way to cast `void *` to `id` but are not 100% clear on this.

The other option, which makes more sense to me personally and I've seen more often I think:

> Mark the object reference as __unsafe_unretained. ... You declare the
>   structure as: `struct x { NSString * __unsafe_unretained S; int X; }`

Hope this helps!